# UICollectionViewCell not setting frames of labels when image is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

What I am trying to do, I am shifting the `UILabel` Frames and `UITextView` upwards when there is no `image`.
It was working correctly when i do this thing locally.But now as the images are downloading from server and when i check for `nil` image, it is giving me wrong output.
**I am trying horizontal scrolling**
Here is the code what I tried

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *myCell=nil;
myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];


UIImageView *ImageView=(UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag:9];
UILabel *questionLabel=(UILabel*)[myCell viewWithTag:567];
UITextView *answerTextView=(UITextView*)[myCell viewWithTag:6];

questionLabel.text=[_questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

answerTextView.text=[_answerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[ImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/%@",[[_arrayOfDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]] ];

if (ImageView.image==nil) {
    //Always Satisfying this condition
    //Set Frame 

    return myCell;
}else{

    return myCell;
    }
}
```

Please provide me with solution.And also the reason Why it is satisfying `if` statement every-time.
(**Autolayout is unchecked**)

Comment: where you have define this csnyImageView? also this is setImageWithURL synchronous call make your view non responding

Comment: @Retro editing mistake.. It was imageView

Comment: @Retro Did you got any solution?
Whats the problem?Why `ImageView.image` is `nil` always?

Comment: it will be nill, i am addding the my solution in answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the AFNetworking for asynchronous solution of your image view update like

```
if (userBasicInfo.userImage == nil) {
            __weak LGMessageBoxCell *weakCell = cell;
            [cell.userImage setImageWithURLRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:userBasicInfo.imageUrl]]
                                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-no-user.png"]
                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                               weakCell.userImage.image = image;
                                               [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
                                               // reload your tableView current cell here
                                           }
                                           failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                           }];
        }
```